# Powershell change the element's value. how to disable it?

Tags: xml, powershell

i am using the flowing code to deal with some xml. but it changed the value! 
how can i correct?

```
$xml =[xml]@'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><zabbix_export><hosts><host name="Template_Snmptrap"><dns></dns></host></hosts><dependencies /></zabbix_export>
'@
$random=Get-Random
$filename="{0}\{1}.xml" -f $env:temp,$random
$xml.save($filename)
get-content $filename
```

the result

```
PS C:\Users\33333> get-content $filename
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<zabbix_export>
  <hosts>
    <host name="Template_Snmptrap">
      <dns>
      </dns>
    </host>
  </hosts>
  <dependencies />
</zabbix_export>
PS C:\Users\33333>
```

[image: the value before and after]

Comment: What exactly did it change? You had `<dns></dns>` in the input.

Answer (score 1):

After you have the XML in $xml, set the `PreserveWhitespace` property to `$true` e.g.:

```
$xml =[xml]@'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><zabbix_export><hosts><hostname="Template_Snmptrap"><dns></dns></host></hosts><dependencies /></zabbix_export>
'@
$xml.PreserveWhitespace = $true
```